# How to make a html page that has a navbar at the top and a sidebar on the left of the bottom half page?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using materializecss and bootstrap. I want to draw something like

```
---------------------------------
---------------------------------
   |
   |
   |
   |
```

Basically, I want the page to be divided into two horizontal section. The top one is the top navbar. In the bottom section, the left section is the left horizontal bar, the section on the right renders another webpage.

My current code looks like:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="main">
            <div class="top">
                <nav class="navbar-fixed">
                </nav>
            </div>
            <div class="bottom">
                <div class="nav">
                    <nav id="left-sidebar-nav"">
                    </nav>
                </div>
                <div id="page1">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

However, the sidebar stretched all the way to the top so it looks like I am breaking my page into two vertical sections rather than horizontal sections. Please help.

Comment: Just to make sure you want a horizontal navbar spanning the entire width of the screen and then a vertical sidebar on the left?

Comment: @RiaanV yes, the vertical navbar on the left of the bottom half (under the horizontal navbar)

Comment: Okay give me a second, also should the sidebar be part of the nav section on the page?

Comment: @RiaanV Well, I am imagining the two navbars serve different purposes, so I don't think they should be in the same nav section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so to get the navbar you use the following code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">

  </div>
</nav>
```

Once you have that in place make sure to remove any margin at the bottom, okay so on to the sidebar what you will have to do is create your sidebar to look the way that you want it to look and add absolute positioning to it so your css would look something like:

```
.sidebar-nav {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
width: 275px;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
list-style: none;
}
```

you can then play with the values to get it to look and act the way you want it

Comment: Is there a fluid way of using navbar? I mean, can I achieve what I want without involving css?

Comment: you could then substitute the <div class="container"> for <div class="container-fluid"> other then that I recommend you check out the default bootstrap documentation at the following link http://getbootstrap.com/components/